# Need to know workarounds to tackle a query plan

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

Need to know workarounds to tackle this [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByXI41ebX).
Tried suggestion given by Brent, but end up with the entire SP itself as topmost cost.
Please let me know if I am missing anything here

Comment: That thing is huge. Can you narrow down some of the areas that are problematic? Providing the DDL for the tables & some test data might help as well.

Comment: You are using a ton of table variables--generally speaking they perform worse than temp tables. That's an easy thing to change and test against the original proc.

Comment: I was reading the free execution plan book on www.sqlservercentral.com and it said to start with the largest arrow since it will be the most expensive part of the plan

Comment: Also, this appears to be an estimated query plan - some problems can be figured out easily if we see an actual plan. That said, picking out the most problematic query, and noting how long it takes to run would help

Answer (score 3):

The plan you posted is an estimated execution plan for a stored procedure with several statements. I've got 2 main pieces of advice based on that:

**First, tune one query at a time.** A stored procedure with this with a lot of different queries, each with their own most expensive operation, can be tough to tackle head on. I bet you've heard the old saying, "How do you eat an elephant? One bite at a time." It's the same thing with query tuning: focus on one query at a time, one operation at a time inside that query.

To figure out which query to focus on, get [sp_BlitzCache](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/) (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors on that open source stored procedure), and run it this way in production:

```
sp_BlitzCache @StoredProcName = 'SPN_AP_GET_TRIAL_BALANCE'
```

That will get you the statements in that stored procedure, sorted by which ones have used the most CPU. (It'll only return results if the query has actually been run recently in production, which may also be a dice roll.) Focus on the top statement that returns. (There are other tricks you can do with sp_BlitzCache, but since you're just starting out here tuning, I'm going to stop there to avoid overwhelming you with details.)

Also note the "Cached Execution Parameters" column of sp_BlitzCache - that gives you the parameters that were cached when SQL Server built that execution plan. Different parameters can produce wildly different execution plans. For more details on that, check out Erland's epic post, [Slow in the App, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

**Second, tune actual plans, not estimates.** The estimated plan is what SQL Server thinks is going to be expensive before the query runs. However, when the estimates are wrong, that's where performance can really go haywire. You want to get as close to the actual plan as you can - which often means getting the right input parameters, and then running it in SSMS with actual execution plans turned on.

Then, you can look at the query plan - but again, focus only on the statement that you identified in the first step as the most resource-intensive. Don't look at the "cost %" lines for each query - those are the estimated costs, even when you're looking at an actual plan.

If you'd like more help from the community, try uploading the actual plan instead of the estimate, and we'll be able to see more details about which lines were really the most resource-intensive. While free volunteers may not wanna tackle an entire stored procedure's estimates, they might be more willing to tackle specific operations in specific actual plans that are running poorly. For even more help, check out my post, [Getting Help with a Slow Query](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/).